# How to run rails bundle install as a cron job in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ubuntu, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ubuntu-12.04

I have a web application which works on ruby on rails 3.2.x under ubuntu 12.04.

During automation of the setup I run install.sh bash file which has bundle install command as below.

```
cd /var/www/myapp
bundle install
bundle update
```

i am automating the setup as to update the latest code from repo. The updated code is available in my repo every 8 hours. Manual setup an setting up test environment is quite tiresome.

Is there anything which I might be missing.

Comment: Why you want to do bundle install as a cron job. Whats the point?

Comment: My point is actually to make few steps as a part of automation. If u have a solution let me know.

Comment: ya me too looking for this only. If anyone knows, please reply. Please activate the question.

Comment: Guys unlock this question, its a simple question.